# Custom User-Agent in youtube-dl python script

Tags: python, python-2.7, user-agent, youtube-dl

I have the following piece of python code which calls youtube-dl and extracts the links that I need.

```
ydl = youtube_dl.YoutubeDL({'outtmpl': '%(id)s%(ext)s'})

with ydl:
    result = ydl.extract_info(
        url,
        download=False
         # We just want to extract the info
    )

if 'entries' in result:
    # Can be a playlist or a list of videos
    video = result['entries'][0]
else:
    # Just a video
    video = result

if video:
    return video

return None
```

But I want to use the custom User-Agent in this program. I know I can specify the custom User-Agent while using the youtube-dl in the command line.

Is there any way I can specify the custom user-agent in the program embedding youtube-dl.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I used Github's code search to find `user-agent` in the YTDL codebase, ended up finding [this piece of code](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/blob/c3bcd206eb031de30179c88ac7acd806a477ceae/youtube_dl/__init__.py#L60-L62) that sets the user agent based on the command line.

So, all in all, just

```
import youtube_dl.utils
youtube_dl.utils.std_headers['User-Agent'] = 'my-user-agent'
```

to override it.